# Skip Immediate Next Cordinate

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a table `foo` where `x`, `y` represents coordinates
How do I discard the immediate next coordinate while using `select`?

```
  x   |  y | value 
------+-----+-------
   32 | 10 |     7
   32 | 11 |     2
   32 | 15 |     2
   32 | 16 |     5
   32 | 21 |    25
   33 | 17 |    57
   33 | 21 |    83
   33 | 22 |    86
```

`Output`

```
  x   |  y | value 
------+-----+-------
   32 | 10 |     7
   32 | 15 |     2
   32 | 21 |    25
   33 | 17 |    57
   33 | 21 |    83
```

Here cordinates `(32,11)`, `(32,16)`, `(33,22)` were skipped since they have an immediate previous coordinate `(32,10) -> (32,11)`, `(32,15) -> (32,16)`, `(32,21) -> (33,22)`

Is this possible using a query? 
I am using Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter out those rows for which a row with the same `x` and the previous `y` exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM my_table AS previous
                  WHERE (previous.x, previous.y )
                      = (my_table.x, my_table.y - 1));
```